# Why my simple pyramid application cannot work with pexpect?

Tags: python, pyramid, pexpect

I have a very simple pyramid application which serves a simple static page. Let's say its name is `mypyramid` and uses port `9999`.

---

If I launch *mypyramid* in another linux console manually, then I **can** use the following code to print out the html string.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import urllib2
    print 'trying to download url'
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:9999/index.html')
    html = response.read()
    print html
```

---

But I want to launch *mypyramid* in an application automatically.

So in my another application, I used `pexpect` to launch *mypyramid*, and then try to get the html string from `http://localhost:9999/index.html`.

```
def _start_mypyramid():
    p = pexpect.spawn(command='./mypyramid')
    return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = _start_mypyramid()
    print p
    print 'mypyramid started'
    import urllib2
    print 'trying to download url'
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:9999/index.html')
    html = response.read()
    print html
```

It seems *mypyramid* has been successfully launched using `pexpect`, as I can see the print of the process and `mypyramid started` has been reached.

However, the application is just **hanging** after `trying to download url`, and I **can't** get anything.

---

What is the solution? I mean I thought `pexpect` would create another process. If that's true, then why it is stopping the retrieval of the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the child returned by pexpect.spawn needs to communicate.
It attempts to write but nobody reads, so the app stops. (I am only guessing though).

If you do not have any reason to use pexpect (which you probably don't if you do not communicate with the child process), why wouldn't you just go for a standard module subprocess?